# Firefox not showing select box correctly after JS Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, firefox

I have the following scenario:

1. I render a popup via Rails & JS to ask for the users login
   credentials
2. The user logs in to his profile
3. Via Rails I render the following HTML:

   ```
   <option value="0003">Company</option>
   <option value="0002" selected="true">Mr.</option>
   <option value="0004">Mr. and Mrs.</option>
   <option value="0001">Ms.</option></select>
   ```

As you can see the HTML is correct but, 
4) If I go watch the page the same HTML is shown: 
[image: Correct screenshot]

But now the plot thickens if I go watch the page nothing is selected in my selectbox:
[image: Image of selectbox]

I think that this is really strange since this works perfectly in IE and Chrome.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location.reload();
```

Did not do the trick so I added:

```
 window.location.reload(true);
```

Now all is fine!

Answer (score 2):

Follow HTML5 standards and use:

`selected = "selected" or "" (empty string) or empty`

> Specifies that this option is pre-selected.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

This should fix the previous error you had of `selected="true"` for one of your `option` tags.

Comment: Woeps wrong value I had already tried to edit it:

I made a new correct screenshot, problem still exists.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/atQrg/ works fine in Chrome, FF, and IE for me. Is your HTML actually formatted as in this fiddle? What versions of the browsers are you running?

Comment: I'm using FireFox 23.0.1. I will say the flow again: 

I visit the page -> Pop up shows -> Fill in the information -> Press Log in -> I'm logged in -> "Page does not reload" -> Some of the information is filled in the textboxes like firstname etc. But the selectboxes are empty.

Comment: Without additional information, I doubt anyone will be able to help you. Does that JSFiddle select fine for you in FF? If so, make sure your HTML is *truly* formatted correctly -- and isn't just being fixed by the browser.  If not, then reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is

```
<option value="0002" selected="selected">Mr.</option>
```

Comment: I have corrected the screenshot, I was trying different options via HTML editor